# Sobreposição da legenda das retas estimadas usando a função stat_poly_eq

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Ajustei diferentes modelos considerando a variável de resposta (massaseca) em função do (tempo) para cada nível de tratamento (teor) usando o pacote ggplot2 combinada com a função stat_poly_eq.

[image]

Porém, como pode ser visto no gráfico a seguir, as legendas das retas estimadas estão sobrepostas. Eu gostaria que eles fossem empilhados no canto esquerdo separadamente. Ao usar a função stat_regline_equation (label.y = 380, label.x = 1000) é possível mover a legenda, no entanto, eles ainda estão sobrepostos.

dados: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y-GsNNcYINqtO-hcJfNRgaj545JZXZIS/view?usp=sharing

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(ggpmisc)

my.formula <- y ~ x
ggplot(dadosnew, aes(x = Tempo, y = massaseca, group = interaction(Fator,Trat),
                     color=interaction(Fator,Trat))) +
  stat_summary(geom = "point", fun = mean) + 
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE,  formula=y ~ poly(x, 1, raw=TRUE)) +
  stat_poly_eq(formula = my.formula,eq.with.lhs = "As-italic(hat(y))~`=`~",
               aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = "*plain(\",\")~")),
               parse = TRUE, size = 5, label.y = 35)+ 
  labs(title = "",
       x = "Time (Minutes)",
       y = "Weight (mg)") + theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 23,color="black"),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 18,color="black"),
        text = element_text(size = 20,color="black")) + facet_wrap(~Fator)
```

Comment: Eu estou votando para fechar esta pergunta porque ela depende de links externos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O método para não sobrepor as equações é usar os argumentos

- `label.x.npc` para o alinhamento no eixo dos x;
- `label.y.npc` para o alinhamento no eixo dos y.

Este último é o que precisa de ser visto com cuidado. Após várias tentativas, encontram-se os valores seguintes:

- `ylim_sup` quanto é preciso aumentar o eixo dos y;
- `xlim_sup` quanto é preciso aumentar o eixo dos x;
- `label_y_npc` a distância entre as equações.

E o código final é então o seguinte.

```
my.formula <- y ~ x
ylim_sup <- 1.1 * max(dadosnew$massaseca)
ylim_inf <- min(dadosnew$massaseca)

label_y_npc <- rep(seq(0.99, by = -0.05, length.out = 5), 2)

dadosnew %>%
  group_by(Tempo, Fator, Trat) %>%
  summarise(massaseca = mean(massaseca, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Tempo, y = massaseca, color = Trat, group = Trat)) +
  geom_point() + 
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE,  formula = y ~ poly(x, 1, raw=TRUE)) +
  stat_poly_eq(formula = my.formula, 
               eq.with.lhs = "italic(hat(y))~`=`~",
               aes(label = paste(..eq.label.., ..rr.label.., sep = "*plain(\", \")~")),
               label.x.npc = "left", 
               label.y.npc = label_y_npc,
               parse = TRUE) + 
  ylim(ylim_inf, ylim_sup) +
  labs(title = "",
       x = "Time (Minutes)",
       y = "Weight (mg)",
       color = "Trat") + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 23,color="black"),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 18,color="black"),
        text = element_text(size = 20,color="black")) + 
  facet_wrap(~Fator)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado @RuiBarradas!!!